# How to order the content generated by *NgFor in rows and columns (FlexLayout) Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, responsive-design, row

I am trying to get the elements generated by *NgFor to be sorted into 3 elements per row.

Currently this code puts all the content of "cont" in a single row.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
 <mat-card  *ngFor="let item of cont">
  <p>{{item.title}}</p>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

but I would like to have something like:

item.title1  item.title2   item.title3

item.title4 item.title5 item.title6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it would be of any help as I see you are asking with flex layout, but what if you use display grid to achieve that.

You would have something like:

```
<div class="grid">
 <mat-card  *ngFor="let item of cont">
  <p>{{item.title}}</p>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

And in your css you can have

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

That way you will always have 3 elements per row

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s5swyy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this.

Give your parent div a width of 100% and then give your mat-cards widths of 33.3% each & and then give your *flex div* (parent-div) the `flex-wrap` property which will allow every 4th mat-card to shift to another line.

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap w-100">
   <mat-card *ngFor="let item of cont" class="w-33">
      <p>{{item}}</p>
   </mat-card>
</div>
```

```scss
.w-33 {
width: 33.3%;
}
```